# REST Query String Parameter

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have the following query string parameters sent from client

```
{"take":75,"skip":0,"page":1,"pageSize":75,"filter":{"logic":"and","filters":
[{"field":"prodCode","operator":"eq","value":"Z20"}]}}:
```

In REST server how could I receive the above format and properly assign to each category?

**Update 1**

```
MultivaluedMap params = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
```

Value of params is

> > {_=[1437904506062], {"take":75,"skip":0,"page":1,"pageSize":75,"filter":{"logic":"and","filters":[{"field":"prodCode","operator":"eq","value":"Z30"}]}}=[]}

Comment: these is a query parameter so you must be getting it using a key. So using that key , store the above in a `String` and then parse as a `JSON`. The you will be able to extract any key/value, as you want. Apologies if i misunderstood the question.

Comment: @AnkitNigam So you mean to say from client side parse the data and sent to server? Could you kindly provide sample code snippet?

Comment: no i meant that client will send the data as it is in a plain text. You can store it in a`String` and then parse it in server side to a `JSON`. Is this what you want, i can provide the snippet if you want the above ?

Comment: @user75ponic provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a query parameter so you must be getting it using a `key` having its value as `{"take":75,"skip":0,"page":1,"pageSize":75,"filter":{"logic":"and","filters":
[{"field":"prodCode","operator":"eq","value":"Z20"}]}}:`. So using that `key` , store the above in a `String` and then parse as a `JSON`( I am using `org.json` here). The you will be able to extract any `key`/`value`, as you want. You could use the code snippet :-

```
String inputValue = @QueryParam(YOUR_KEY); // OR whatever way you get it
        /*
         * This inputValue will actually contain your value :-
         * {"take":75,"skip":0,"page":1,
         * "pageSize":75,"filter":{"logic":"and","filters":
         * [{"field":"prodCode","operator":"eq","value":"Z20"}]}}
         */

        JSONObject inputJSON = new JSONObject(inputValue); 
        //Now getting values from input JSON
        int take = inputJSON.getInt("take");
        int skip = inputJSON.getInt("skip");
        int page = inputJSON.getInt("page");
        int pageSize = inputJSON.getInt("pageSize");
        JSONObject filter = inputJSON.getJSONObject("filter"); // filter is again a JSONObject 
        String logic = filter.getString("logic");
        System.out.println(take + " "+skip + " "+page + " "+pageSize + " "+logic);
        JSONArray filters = filter.getJSONArray("filters"); // filters is a JSONArray

        for(int i = 0; i< filters.length(); i++){  // iterating over JSONArray 
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject)filters.get(i); 
        String field = jo.getString("field"); 
        String operator = jo.getString("operator"); 
        String value = jo.getString("value"); 
        System.out.println(field + " "+operator + " "+value ); 
}
```

Output :-

```
75 0 1 75 and
prodCode eq Z20
```

Comment: @user75ponic try printing `inputJSON ` and see what it contains,using `System.out.println(inputJSON`);`, also print the `inputValue`

Comment: It should be something like `{"pageSize":75,"take":75,"filter":{"filters":[{"value":"Z20","operator":"eq","field":"prodCode"}],"logic":"and"},"page":1,"skip":0}`. Can you try printing the `inputValue` instead

Comment: @user75ponic the way you are taking the query parameter is having some discrepancy, I have provided the solution considering the  String you provided in OP

Comment: @user75ponic this wont work for `MultivaluedMap`, earlier you gave `JSON` , for that it will for sure work.

Comment: @user75ponic so whats the input now ?

Comment: Thanks Ankit for the insight.

Comment: @user75ponic glad that it helped :)